# switch_to method

Tags: selenium

Does anyone how to switch to a new window in selenium-webdriver?

I am hitting link in Facebook that launches a new window.  I tried:

```
browser.switch_to.window
```

But that resulted in this error:

> ERROR:
>   Wrong number of Arguments 0 for 1

What should I pass to the method?

Comment: I don't think this is Java!
Please mention the language. If you have found the answer please update it here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for switching to latest/new window:

```
//Java binding code

for(String windowHdl : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(windowHdl);
}
```